# How do you comment out code inside a php funciton?

Tags: php

For a php function code, how do you comment out a code?  Is this correct or what is the best way?

```
function menu_element_builder($values) {
//$links = '';
}
```

Comment: // and /* */ .. i dunno if there is a best way in commenting code :D

Comment: Well if you need to comment out code you should ask yourself why you need it? And if you don't just can delete it.

Comment: I just wasn't sure if the syntax worked the same inside a function.  Now I know!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.comments.php

Answer (score 3):

Comment out lines with `//` or `#`, up to you.

Comment parts of lines, or entire code blocks, with `/* [commented code] */`.

```
function menu_element_builder($values/*, $optional_value*/) {
    #Commented out line
    echo "Not commented out";     

    //Commented out line
    echo "Not commented out";

    /* Commented out code block
    echo "Commented out"; */

    echo "Not commented out"; //but this is ." and so's this";
    echo "Not commented out" /* but this is */ ." and this isn't";
    /* This is commented out */ echo "But this isn't";
}
```

Comment: Do not use #, i believe it is deprecated. Use // or /* */

Comment: @Nitin its only deprecated in .ini files. Its fine for PHP Files.

Comment: @Nitin Actually they're not - they're only deprecated in `.ini` files. [Source](http://php.net/manual/en/migration53.deprecated.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// This is a single-line comment

# This is also a single-line comment

/*
This is a multiple-lines comment block
that spans over multiple
lines
*/

// Aswell you can use comments to hide part of your code from execution
$x = 5 /* + 15 */ + 5;
echo $x;
?>
```